# Postgres: Count number of users actions within time interval

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to count kind of DAU by specified actions, where users are divided into categories by number of their actions within some interval.

**Raw data example:**

```
date        user_id   amount_actions
2018-12-01  1         2      
2018-12-02  1         1
2018-12-10  1         1
2018-12-01  2         2      
2018-12-02  2         1
2018-12-10  3         1
```

**Result table I wish I could have:**

```
date        user_id   amount_actions rolling_sum_7_days
2018-12-01  1         2              2
2018-12-02  1         1              3
2018-12-10  1         1              1
2018-12-01  2         2              2
2018-12-12  2         1              1
2018-12-10  3         1              1
2018-12-15  3         1              2
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why source table has 6 rows and result has 7 rows?

Comment: Sorry, did a mistake while copying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a lateral join that calculates the sum of actions for that user in the past seven days:

```
select  date
,       user_id
,       amount_actions
,       sum_actions
from    YourTable yt1
cross join lateral
        (
        select  sum(amount_actions) as sum_actions
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt1.user_id = yt2.user_id
                and yt1.date - interval '7 days' < yt2.date
                and yt2.date <= yt1.date
        ) sum_actions
```

[Working example at rextester.](https://rextester.com/JZOP74550)

Answer (score 1):

Using a cumulative sum on Postgres:

```
select
    dt, user_id, amount_actions,
    to_char(dt, 'WWYYYY') wk,
    sum(amount_actions) 
        over 
        (partition by user_id, to_char(dt, 'WWYYYY')
         order by user_id, dt) rolling_sum_7_days
from
    tbl
order by user_id, dt;
```

The partition is: `user_id` + `WeekYear` to_char(dt, 'WWYYYY')

> ```
> dt         | user_id | amount_actions | wk     | rolling_sum_7_days
> :--------- | ------: | -------------: | :----- | -----------------:
> 2018-12-01 |       1 |              2 | 482018 |                  2
> 2018-12-02 |       1 |              1 | 482018 |                  3
> 2018-12-10 |       1 |              1 | 502018 |                  1
> 2018-12-01 |       2 |              2 | 482018 |                  2
> 2018-12-02 |       2 |              1 | 482018 |                  3
> 2018-12-10 |       3 |              1 | 502018 |                  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ad180b1745bcbd30b914cf12cd43158b)*

Comment: This looks at whole weeks, not the last 7 days?